# Usage of Javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I think this is so basic so people maybe minus votes on this document, but even so this is so confused me about callback function in JavaScript.

```
function doSomething(callback){ 
    setTimeout(hello,5000);
    callback();
}


function hi(){
    console.log("hi");
}

function hello(){
    console.log("hello");
}

doSomething(hi);

/* result */
// hi
// (after 5 seconds) hello
```

I want to use callback function as a handle function's execute order, so I decided use callback pattern. In above code, I think after 5 seconds, the  callback function should be executed, but why callback ignore before function and was ran first? Could you tell me a some hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Because your timeout doesn't include the `callback`, it runs on its own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `callback()` was executing after the execution of the line `setTimeout()` but the callback of `setTimeout` will trigger after `5000ms`, that is the expected behaviour. So if you want `callback()` to exeute after `hello()` do:

```
function doSomething(callback){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        hello();
        callback();
    },5000);
}
```